# Default own values in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I learn SQL from this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

```
SELECT LastName,FirstName FROM Persons
```

this show me:

```
LastName   |    FirstName
Hanse      |        Ola
Svendson   |    Tove
Pettersen  |    Kari
```

how can i add for this own columns without get data from DATABASE?
for example:

```
SELECT TEST(default: aaa), LastName,FirstName FROM Persons
```

this should show me:

```
TEST | LastName   | FirstName
aaa  | Hanse      |        Ola
aaa  | Svendson   | Tove
aaa  | Pettersen  | Kari
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a "default" value on an actual field in a table you could use either the [Coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) or [IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) functions (please assume that Test is an actual field):

```
SELECT COALESCE(test, 'aaa') as Test, LastName,FirstName FROM Persons

SELECT ISNULL(test, 'aaa') as Test, LastName,FirstName FROM Persons
```

Both of these will return either the actual value of the field Test or 'aaa' if Test is Null.

We use COALESCE when retrieving the next Primary Key from a table (we don't use the Identity Property to maintain our PK's)

```
SELECT (COALESCE(MAX(PK), 0) + 1) FROM TableName
```

This way if there if the table doesn't contain any rows then 1 will be returned.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT 'aaa' as test, LastName,FirstName FROM Persons
```

Answer (score 0):

Randy has given best approach for an imagery field but if `test` is an actual field you can do this too..

```
select case when test is null then 'aaa' else test end, LastName,FirstName 
FROM Persons;
```

will return `aaa` if `test` is null else `test`'s value.